# Integrate $f(x,y,z) = x+ y+ z$ over the plane $2x + 2y + z = 8$ that lies in the first quadrant

Tags: multivariable-calculus, solution-verification, multiple-integral

> Integrate $f(x,y,z) = x+ y+ z$ over the plane $2x + 2y + z = 8$ that
>   lies in the first quadrant

My answer:

I set up the following integral

$$\int\int_R\int_{z = 0}^{8-2(x+y)} (x+y+z) \:dz dR$$ where $R: x+ y = 4$ so we get

$$I = \int_{x=0}^4\int_{y=0}^{4-x}\int_{z = 0}^{8-2(x+y)} (x+y+z )\:dzdydx$$

Is this integral set up correctly?

Comment: Looks good to me!

Comment: Please confirm it because my answer is not matching the answer my instructor gave me

Comment: Confirm what in particular?  That you set it up correctly, or that you're integrating it correctly?  Those are different questions...

Comment: This question is a bit confusing. I dont understand they are asking the volume integral or surface integral.@Abhay

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** You are asked to integrate $f(x,y,z)$ over the surface of the given plane (say $S$) in first octant, so it is a surface  integral, i.e.  $\iint_{S} f(x,y,z) dS.$

Now, on $xy$-plane, $dS=\sqrt{1+z_x^{2}+z_y^{2}}dxdy=3dxdy$. We use the equation of the plane in $f(x,y,z)$ which gives:

> $$\iint_{S} f(x,y,z) dS=3\int_{x=0}^4 \int_{y=0}^{4-x} (8-x-y) dxdy.$$

I hope, you may take it from here.